# Can one use exsheets to produce a marks layout after each question?

Tags: exsheets

I'm trying to get an exam layout of the form:

```
1. Blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah  [ ]
blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahbla
hblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah.
```

where [ ] should be a fairly large (1 cm x 1 cm) square, that is aligned with the first line of each question. I can use `exsheets` and `changepage` to produce a list of questions with a proper right margin, but I do not know if I can either use `exsheets` to define a new question environment that places such box accordingly (I think this should be possible, given the flexibility of the package) or perhaps use another package to achieve this.

*Update*. I managed to achieve what I intended with the `minipage` environment. Is there a better option? I still cannot get the first sentence aligned correctly, however.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11  pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{exsheets} 
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin-nr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \posttitle{%
        \par\end{center}
        \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
        \vskip0.5em}%
            }

\title{Title goes here}
\subtitle{Subtitle goes here}
\date{\vspace{-15ex}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\hrulefill
\vspace{0.5 em}

    \textsc{Your name}: \dotfill \textsc{Your major:} \dotfill

    \textsc{Your ID}: \dotfill \textsc{Your page tally}: \dotfill

\hrulefill

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.85\textwidth}
    \begin{question} \lipsum[1]
        \end{question}
    \end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
    \flushright
        \framebox(20,20){} 
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.85\textwidth}
    \begin{question} \lipsum[2]
        \end{question}
    \end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.15\textwidth}
    \flushright
        \framebox(20,20){} 
\end{minipage}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for putting the `question` environment in `minipage`s or defining new environments… This is the `exsheets` way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\DeclareExSheetsHeadingContainer{square}{\framebox(20,20){}}

\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{custom}{default}{
  runin = true ,
  number-post-code = \space ,
  attach = { main[l,t]square[r,t](\textwidth,0pt) } ,
  join   = { main[r,vc]number[l,vc](0pt,0pt) }
}

\usepackage{scrextend}% provides the addmargin environment
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = custom ,
  question/pre-hook = \addmargin[0pt]{.15\textwidth} ,
  question/post-hook = \endaddmargin
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Using [`xsim`](http://www.mychemistry.eu/2017/02/improving-exsheets/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim)) – the result looks the same:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xsim,needspace,adjustbox,scrextend}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
  exercise/template    = square
}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{square}
  {%
    \Needspace*{2\baselineskip}%
    \addmargin[0pt]{.15\textwidth}%
    \par\noindent
    \adjustbox{
      fbox = 1pt 0pt,
      lap = {\textwidth},
      valign = t,
      set vsize = {0pt}{0pt}
    }{\rule{0pt}{20pt}\hspace{20pt}}%
    \textbf{\GetExerciseProperty{counter}} %
  }
  {\endaddmargin\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill

\begin{exercise}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

---

BTW: `flushright` is an *environment* (`\begin{flushright}...\end{flushright}`) and *not* to be used as command (`\flushright`). The corresponding command is called `\raggedleft`!

Answer (score 1):

For the correct alignment you can play with `minipage` options.

For convenience, I've created a new enviroment (but nesting environments are too much above my level of knowledge, hence you have to use `question` environment within mine).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11  pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{exsheets} 
\SetupExSheets{headings=runin-nr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
    \posttitle{%
        \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}

\title{Title goes here}
\subtitle{Subtitle goes here}
\date{\vspace{-15ex}}
\newenvironment{myquest}{%
\begin{minipage}[t][\height][t]{.85\textwidth}
}{%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][26pt][b]{.15\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
    \framebox(20,20){} 
\end{minipage}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\hrulefill
\vspace{0.5 em}

\textsc{Your name}: \dotfill \textsc{Your major:} \dotfill

\textsc{Your ID}: \dotfill \textsc{Your page tally}: \dotfill

\hrulefill
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{myquest}
    \begin{question} 
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{question}
\end{myquest}

\begin{myquest}
    \begin{question} 
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{question}
\end{myquest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It's likely there's a better solution using `exsheets` options, but I don't know that package, maybe I'll edit my answer after reading its documentation (if someone else doesn't answer before me).

*Edit*: see clemens's answer for an `exsheets` solution.